# Function to display Images based on category on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Hi There I am writing some PHP code to get some images assigned a custom category given to them via a WordPress Plugin which allows me to assign category's to individual images.  The code is below is what I have at the moment

```
function showFooterImages() {

$footerImagesArray = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'category' => 'footer-images',
);

 
// Query to get footer images
$footerImagesQuery = new WP_Query( $footerImagesArray );
 
// The Loop
if ( $the_query-> have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $footerImagesQuery->have_posts() ) {
        $footerImagesQuery->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_post() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} 
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

If I replace the

```
echo '<li>' . get_the_post() . '</li>';
```

with the following

```
echo "<p> this is a test </p>";
```

I do get 4 lines of text from the echo showing it is working and if i change the posts_per_page to 6 for example I then get 6 however I am struggling to get the images even displaying and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think using `get_the_post` makes sense, if you want to display the actual images. Should probably much rather be using `wp_get_attachment_image`

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the advise was able to get this working with your push in the right direction thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get this working with some advice from CBroe  for some reason cant tag him but he pointed me in the right direction

Got this working by doing the following

```
  function showFooterImages() {
$footerImagesArray = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'category' => 'footer-images',
);
// Query to get footer images
    $footerImagesQuery = new WP_Query( $footerImagesArray );
    $images = array();
        foreach ( $footerImagesQuery->posts as $image ) {
            ?>
                <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID ) ; ?>">
            <?php
        }
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```